# Insert Look up Fields in list dynamically

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I have a scenario in which the user will upload Excel files in a document library created in the Root Web in a predefined format. There are two properties in the document library for `SiteName` and `ListName`. Now a timer job will be responsible to insert the data in the Excel file in the Site/List provided in the properties.

The issue I am facing is that there will be some Lookup Columns in the target lists and the user will only provide the values in the Excel File without lookup Ids and as the Site and Lists are dynamic I will not be able to query the source list for lookup columns.

```
using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
{
    SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists[BulkUploadLibraryName];

    SPQuery docLibQuery = new SPQuery();
    docLibQuery.Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) + "</Value></Geq></Where>";
    SPListItemCollection collection = docLib.GetItems();

    foreach (SPListItem listItem in collection)
    {
        LinkFieldValue webField = (LinkFieldValue)listItem["SiteName"];
        LinkFieldValue listField = (LinkFieldValue)listItem["ListName"];
        var data = ExcelHelper.Read(web.Url + "//" + listItem.Url);
        List<ConfigItem> errorList = new List<ConfigItem>();

        using (SPWeb targetWeb = site.OpenWeb(webField.NavigateUrl))
        {
            SPList targetList = targetWeb.GetList(listField.NavigateUrl.Replace(" ", "%20"));                        

            foreach (ConfigItem configItem in data)
            {                            
                SPListItem item = targetList.Items.Add();
                SPFieldLookupValueCollection category = item["Category"] as SPFieldLookupValueCollection;
                SPFieldLookupValueCollection subCategory = item["SubCategory"] as SPFieldLookupValueCollection;

                item["Title"] = configItem.Title;
                item["City"] = configItem.City;
                item["Longitude"] = configItem.Longitude;
                item["Latitude"] = configItem.Latitude;
                item["Address"] = configItem.Address;
                item["Region"] = configItem.Region;
                item["WorkingDays"] = configItem.WorkingDays;
                item["WorkingHours"] = configItem.WorkingHours;
                item["LocationID"] = configItem.BranchID;
                item["Category"] = category;
                item["SubCategory"] = subCategory;
                try
                {
                    item.Update();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    configItem.Exception = ex.Message;
                    errorList.Add(configItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: added the code. I have issues with the Category and Sub Category fields.